How to click a link (<a></a>) inside a vue.js v-tooltip? Is it possible to do?
In my vue.js app, I am implementing a vue.js component with a v-tooltip to display it's content with multiple entries. One of the entry is a anchor link. The tooltip is working using mouse hover, so as soon as the mouse is hovered outside of the item it tooltip is no longer visible. How do I get around the issue so that a link inside the tooltip can be clicked?
Here is my vue.js component

Vue.component('label-provider-item',
{
props: ['item'],
template:'tooltip.top="{show: item.pageingNote || !item.pagerId,
content:createTooltipHtmlContent(item),
trigger:'hover'}">{{item.label}}' methods: { >createTooltipHtmlContent:
createTooltipHtmlContent }
} );


First off, this is not good UX.
A tooltip should only be informative and not interactive.
Meanwhile, you could get around that issue by:

putting a hover area bigger than the element itself,
or leaving some time before the tooltip hides leaving the time for the user to click on it
or change the behavior of "just hovering" into making the tooltip'ed element clickable


TLDR: don't do it because it will be bad in terms of:

mobile support
accessibility
ease of use
familiarity, who clicked on such a thing ever?


thank you for your comment. I have decided not to do that any more.
One other question. I noticed that my tooltip content showed when the application is launched before any hovering is done.     How do I prevent that? Keep in mind that the content of the tooltip is generated by a function.

@dvn I guess it depends on how you render your app and the CSS around the tooltip. Might it be visible by default? Do you have some state plugged into it?

Fixed it. The issue is in a different area where data is populated.
